# docker logs err:"+ sudo -E kolla_set_configs sudo: unknown uid 42401: who are you?" in openstack container

Tags: python, docker, configuration, ansible, openstack

Multinodes(3 nodes) openstack cluster deploy by `kolla-ansible`, two nodes(2nd and 3rd nodes) are working well, the one node(1st_node) have some containers always **Restarting** with the error logs, e.g. `kolla_toolbox` container:

```
+ sudo -E kolla_set_configs
sudo: unknown uid 42401: who are you?
```

I had check the `kolla_toolbox` container's `/etc/passwd` file, it has the same `md5sum` with the other two normal nodes. And the `/etc/passwd` file has the line with the content: `ansible:x:42401:42401::/var/lib/ansible:/usr/sbin/nologin`.

The result of `id 42401` and `id ansible` in all containers of three nodes are:

```
uid=42401(ansible) gid=42401(ansible) groups=42401(ansible),42400(kolla)
```

in three hypervisor nodes are:

```
:no such user
```

I had ran `docker image rm kolla_toolbox`, `pull` it and `deploy` in 1st_node, the issue still exist, but it works on the other two nodes.

What's wrong with the 1st_node about the docker or container?

How could I fix it?

*kolla_set_configs* is a python file in the path of `/usr/local/bin/kolla_set_configs` which only found inside the container, and I can't figure out which line about the **[kolla_set_configs](https://github.com/openstack/kolla/blob/master/docker/base/set_configs.py)** file make the error logs.

Comment: Please paste the output of `id 42401; id ansible` from all three nodes (obviously the id won't work on node1, but you'll have to compare). I had a similar issue in a baremetal installation of openstack where we had to reinstall a control node, and the uid/gid of the critical users (cinder, nova) were different. We use a mounted cephfs to be able to live-migrate and for cinder conversion. I wouldn't know how to fix this except redeploy all containers with the exact same version so the UID/GID are the same.

Comment: @eblock thanks, the `id 42401; id ansible` only get result in the containers, they all have the same result in three nodes's containers, I had update the question, plz check.

Comment: @eblock you save my time, I fixed it by redeploy all containers on 1st_node. Could you add that to answer, and I want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the ID of the ansible user is the same across all three nodes for the kolla_toolbox container, but maybe there's another reference or condition or dependency to other containers where the UID is different. I had a similar issue in a baremetal installation of openstack where we had to reinstall a control node, and the uid/gid of the critical users (cinder, nova) were different. We use a mounted cephfs to be able to live-migrate and for cinder conversion. I don't see another way to fix this than to redeploy all containers (on first node) with the exact same version so the UID/GID are the same.